# Does the inline-skate weight refer to one or both skates?

Tags: equipment, skating, inline-skating

I'm looking at various inline-skate sites and all refer to weight without specifying whether it is for one skate or for the pair. (e.g. [here](https://www.skatepro.com/en-us/23-7195.htm))

So I guess there must be a rule when referring to inline-skate weight that I miss.

So is it for one or both skates?

Comment: Not sure why [tag:inline-skating] doesn't exist given the [tag:skating] tag mentions it; probably just an oversight.  Inline skating is certainly a sport and thus on topic, so I've added the tag.  (If you're using these in [tag:inline-hockey], please use that tag instead, as while this is probably generic to either, you should use the best tag for your use case.)  Do note that *physical fitness* topics are off topic here (as we have a sister site, [fitness.se], for those); so if you're really intending to ask questions in the fitness realm, that might be a better site to ask those.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to contact the manufacturer or retailer for exact specs, especially since weight varies by size, as well as having limited comparative value when skates have very different wheel/bearing selections which make a big difference on total weight.

Aggressive inline skates weigh around 1kg-1.5kg, or around 2.5-3.5 pounds, per skate.  See for example [this discussion of weight](http://www.skatelogforum.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3991), which while a bit out of date is still within reason for current models.  As such, you can surmise that the site you linked is mentioning the weight for *one* skate.